# Why does we need libstdc++.so?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, posix, standards

- Most components of the C++ standard library are exported in source
  code form, that is, provided in header files only.
- Most functions of the C library are provided by libc.so.

So, my questions are:

**Why does we need libstdc++.so?**

**What contents are in libstdc++.so?**

Comment: See for yourself: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src

Comment: Your first sentence is entirely incorrect. Your question is based on a false premiss. And even if it were true, the fact that there is even one symbol that isn't 'exported in source form' is sufficient explanation, so your question also relies on a *non sequitur.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of symbols which are defined in the library. Notably, much of the language support and all of the standard library exception classes are defined in library.

Even if many of components in the standard C++ library are templates and, thus, have an inline definition, they do benefit from being explicitly instantiated. Using explicit instantiations of the IOStreams library (and declaring them as `extern` templates) greatly improves compile-times.

To figure out what symbols are defined in the library use `nm`: it will print the symbols defined and referenced by a library. The names may be mangled which will be fixed by piping the result to a suitable `c++filt`.

Comment: Weren't extern templates deprecated because no one could figure out what that means?

Comment: @ShacharShemesh: *exported* template were *removed* (not just deprecated) although primarily because they didn't quite deliver what they were meant to deliver and most implementers didn't want to implement them. There isn't anything problematic or hard to understand about `extern` templates: an `extern` template simply declares that no implicit instantiation shall be done for the declared instantiation. Instead, a suitable explicit instantiation will be provided.